# R: Caret Package preProcess()

Tags: r, r-caret

I am fairly new to data modelling and R, I wonder if anyone could give me some advice.

I am using R to replicate a model I have built in SPSS modeller with the view of then trying to improve it. Currently I am building a basic linear model using the caret package.

I have used preProcess() to scale and centre my numeric fields, including the numeric variable which the model is predicting.

```
preProcValues <- preProcess(Data_Numeric, method = c("center", "scale"))
Data_PreProc <- predict(preProcValues, Data_Numeric)
```

When I produce the model I find that this pre-processing results in a more accurate model, however, I am unsure how to take the scaled and centred result and get a 'result'. The model is used as a pricing tool so I need to unscale and centre it if that makes sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `centering`, the sample mean is subtracted while the centered values are divided by the standard deviation for `scaling`.

It'd be easily recovered from the following relationships.

- data
- centered = data - mean(data)
- scaled = centered / sd(data)

Comment: Thank you, this should do the job.